# How to select a cell content in a table when there is no id or class using jquery

Tags: jquery, displaytag

I have a table generated by displaytags and it looks like below.

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="coldata">
    <td>02063873320</td>
    <td>ORD81268679</td>
    <td>80%</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>84070063962913</td>
    <td><img src="xyz"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    .
    .
    .
  </tr>
```

Each row has an image in the last cell and when i click on the cell i want to call a Jquery function which will send the 5th cell's value in that row to an action class.

i want to know how to select the 5th cell and function to an action class. Can anyone suggest the selector and function to call action class

Comment: This has nothing to do with `java` or `jsp`, I've removed those tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rows all have that `coldata` class, you can get the fifth cells (index 4) using [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) like this:

```
var fifthCells = $("tr.coldata td:eq(4)");
```

...and then hook their `click` event, and navigate from there:

```
fifthCells.click(function() {
    var $td = $(this); // The specific `td` that was clicked
    // ...do something with that specific `td`
});
```

If it's not always the *fifth* cell but always the one before the *last*, you can use [`last-of-type`](http://api.jquery.com/last-of-type-selector/):

```
var lastCells = $("tr.coldata td:last-of-type").prev('td');
```

Or if they're the only ones prior to ones with `img` elements in them:

```
var cellsWithImages = $("tr.coldata td img").closest("td").prev('td');
```

...and so on.

---

Side note: If the contents of the table are dynamic (or arguably even if they aren't), it may be useful to use a *delegated* handler. Here's the delegated `click` handler for the fifth `td` in each row:

```
// fifthCells
$("table.some-class").on("click", "tr.coldata td:eq(4)" function() {
    // `this` is the DOM element for the td that was clicked
});
```

Comment: there are multiple rows and all of them have the coldata class.. if i click on the second row's image, i need to get the 5 th cell in the second row. dosent the above selector select the 5th cell in every row?

Comment: @DJR: Yes, but then when you're processing the event, you have a reference to the *specific* `td` that was clicked (see update).